# Remove brackets and commas in output from Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Currently my output is as below:

```
((130,1))
((131,1))
((132,1))
((133,1))
((137,1))
((138,2))
((139,1))
((140,1))
((142,2))
((143,1))
```

I want to have it like:

```
130 1
131 1
132 1
```

My code is given below:

```
A = LOAD 'user-links-small.txt' AS (user_a: int, user_b: int);
B = ORDER A BY user_a;
grouped = COGROUP B BY user_a;
C = FOREACH grouped GENERATE COUNT(B);
D = COGROUP C BY $0;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE($0, COUNT($1));
DUMP E;
```

I was looking through these forums, and some suggested that the way to this was by coding a user-defined function. I can try that, but I am new to Pig and want to learn its functions a bit more in details. I found something on flatten() but can't really get that output. Is there a way to remove the brackets and commas as shown? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **DUMP** command by default the output will be stored as tuples (ie all the fields dumped inside function bracket separated by delimiter **','**)

You can remove the first bracket using **FLATTEN** operator and second bracket and **','** using **STORE** command.

Try this

```
E = FOREACH D GENERATE FLATTEN(($0, COUNT($1)));
STORE E INTO 'output' USING PigStorage(' ');
```

Go to the folder **'output'** and check the file name starts with part*. you will see the output like this
130 1
131 1
132 1